# Ltspice running but gives error log. Ignore?

Tags: ltspice

When I run my simulation it works fine but this log file appears when I close out the simulation. It started this when I changed a third party part that was not working with the model of that part from the mfgrs. list of models. Here is the contents. Can I ignore it and proceed on?

```
R26: both pins shorted together -- ignoring.
Error on line 1843 : .model m6:bsim3 nmos (level=7 version=3.1 mobmod=3 capmod=2 paramchk=1 nqsmod=0  tox=970e-10 xj=1.4e-6 nch=1.7e17 ua=1.6e-9  u0=700 vsat=1.0e5 drout=3.0 pvag=5  delta=0.10 pscbe2=0 rsh=1.0e-3 pdiblc2=1e-7  vth0=3.50 voff=-0.1 nfactor=1.1  lint=5.90e-7 dlc=5.90e-7 fc=0.5  cgso=1.12e-9 cgsl=0 cgdo=1.05e-14  cgdl=1.68e-9 cj=0 cf=0  ckappa=0.20 kt1=-2.07 kt2=0  ua1=1.02e-9 nj=10 )
    * Unrecognized parameter "fc" -- ignored
Error on line 1843 : .model m5:bsim3 nmos (level=7 version=3.1 mobmod=3 capmod=2 paramchk=1 nqsmod=0  tox=970e-10 xj=1.4e-6 nch=1.7e17 ua=1.6e-9  u0=700 vsat=1.0e5 drout=3.0 pvag=5  delta=0.10 pscbe2=0 rsh=1.0e-3 pdiblc2=1e-7  vth0=3.50 voff=-0.1 nfactor=1.1  lint=5.90e-7 dlc=5.90e-7 fc=0.5  cgso=1.12e-9 cgsl=0 cgdo=1.05e-14  cgdl=1.68e-9 cj=0 cf=0  ckappa=0.20 kt1=-2.07 kt2=0  ua1=1.02e-9 nj=10 )
    * Unrecognized parameter "fc" -- ignored
WARNING: Less than two connections to node NC_01.  This node is used by R:SV1PSPOT:1.
WARNING: Less than two connections to node N003.  This node is used by V2.
Warning: Pscbe2 = 0 is not positive.
Warning: Pd = 0 is less than W.
Warning: Ps = 0 is less than W.
Warning: Pscbe2 = 0 is not positive.
Warning: Pd = 0 is less than W.
Warning: Ps = 0 is less than W.
Instance "m:m3:1": Length shorter than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
Instance "m:m3:1": Width narrower than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
Per .tran options, skipping operating point for transient analysis.

NOTE:  Since output waveform compression is enabled and not all nodes(currents) are
       saved, it is possible to have compression artifacts in the output data.

Heightened Def Con from 0.428853 to 0.428853

Date: Thu Jul 06 07:04:21 2017
Total elapsed time: 5.890 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = modified trap
totiter = 36564
traniter = 36564
tranpoints = 14814
accept = 10157
rejected = 4658
matrix size = 269
fillins = 417
solver = Normal
Thread vector: 107.1/66.2[2] 23.7/13.8[2] 12.2/7.0[2] 3.6/91.3[1]  2592/500
Matrix Compiler1: 43.39 KB object code size  23.1/12.7/[12.9]
Matrix Compiler2: off  [6.5]/7.1/7.6
```

Comment: You need to decide for yourself if every of those has an impact or is a sign of a mistake. I rarely short over resistors in simulations, so the question is why you did that and if it is ok. For the parameters, these are not parameters that ltspice knows about, so why did you put them there? Did you blindly copypasta some model meant for some other spice that may or may not work as intended with ltspice?

Comment: It may be ignored, unless you know that the `fc` parameter is critical. The log says: "ignoring", which means it considers you know what you are doing and know that the parameter isn't recognized. If it is so, it's up to you. The messages about width/length may also be ignored, unless, again, you know they are wrong. LTspice makes certain assumptions, but they're not fixed in stone, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the shorts which were some parts that were not being used and were not needed. Here is the new text I get after fixing those things. Also I will include the part that I got from the manufactures website. I guess I assumed it would be a good part. It replaced the same part that I was using from a third party that did not work at all but that part did not giver errors.

```
Error on line 1747 : .model m6:bsim3 nmos (level=7 version=3.1 mobmod=3 capmod=2 paramchk=1 nqsmod=0  tox=970e-10 xj=1.4e-6 nch=1.7e17 ua=1.6e-9  u0=700 vsat=1.0e5 drout=3.0 pvag=5  delta=0.10 pscbe2=0 rsh=1.0e-3 pdiblc2=1e-7  vth0=3.50 voff=-0.1 nfactor=1.1  lint=5.90e-7 dlc=5.90e-7 fc=0.5  cgso=1.12e-9 cgsl=0 cgdo=1.05e-14  cgdl=1.68e-9 cj=0 cf=0  ckappa=0.20 kt1=-2.07 kt2=0  ua1=1.02e-9 nj=10 )
   * Unrecognized parameter "fc" -- ignored
Error on line 1747 : .model m5:bsim3 nmos (level=7 version=3.1 mobmod=3 capmod=2 paramchk=1 nqsmod=0  tox=970e-10 xj=1.4e-6 nch=1.7e17 ua=1.6e-9  u0=700 vsat=1.0e5 drout=3.0 pvag=5  delta=0.10 pscbe2=0 rsh=1.0e-3 pdiblc2=1e-7  vth0=3.50 voff=-0.1 nfactor=1.1  lint=5.90e-7 dlc=5.90e-7 fc=0.5  cgso=1.12e-9 cgsl=0 cgdo=1.05e-14  cgdl=1.68e-9 cj=0 cf=0  ckappa=0.20 kt1=-2.07 kt2=0  ua1=1.02e-9 nj=10 )
   * Unrecognized parameter "fc" -- ignored
Warning: Pscbe2 = 0 is not positive.
Warning: Pd = 0 is less than W.
Warning: Ps = 0 is less than W.
Warning: Pscbe2 = 0 is not positive.
Warning: Pd = 0 is less than W.
Warning: Ps = 0 is less than W.
Instance "m:m3:1": Length shorter than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
Instance "m:m3:1": Width narrower than recommended for a level 1 MOSFET.
Per .tran options, skipping operating point for transient analysis.
Heightened Def Con from 0.589734 to 0.589734

Date: Fri Jul 07 08:38:35 2017
Total elapsed time: 36.055 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = modified trap
totiter = 236482
traniter = 236482
tranpoints = 62603
accept = 46734
rejected = 15870
matrix size = 262
fillins = 428
solver = Normal
Matrix Compiler1: 44.92 KB object code size  23.9/41.1/[8.5]
Matrix Compiler2: 29.26 KB object code size  7.3/18.3/[4.6]
```

Heres the part file that caused this error log when I added it with a `.include` statement.

```
**************** Power Discrete MOSFET Electrical Circuit Model *****************
** Product Name: FQH8N100C
** 1000V N-Channel MOSFET and TO-247
** Model Type: BSIM3V3
**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.SUBCKT FQH8N100C 2 1 3    
*Nom Temp=25 deg C
Dbody 7 5    DbodyMOD
Dbreak 5 11  DbreakMOD
Ebreak 11 7 17 7 1000
Lgate 1 9    1.125e-9
Ldrain 2 5   1.440e-9
Lsource 3 7  9.106e-10
RLgate 1 9   11.25
RLdrain 2 5  14.4
RLsource 3 7 9.11
Rgate 9 6    0.5
It 7 17      1
Rbreak 17 7  RbreakMOD 1
.MODEL RbreakMOD RES (TC1=1.18e-3 TC2=-1.15e-6)
.MODEL DbodyMOD D (IS=6.45e-9  N=1.5      RS=4.44e-3   TRS1=3.8e-3 TRS2=5.8e-6 
+ CJO=1.76e-09     M=0.53      VJ=0.45    TT=1.09e-6   XTI=3       EG=1.154)
.MODEL DbreakMOD D (RS=100e-3 TRS1=1.0e-3 TRS2=5.0e-6)
Rdrain 5 16 RdrainMOD 1.2
.MODEL RdrainMOD RES (TC1=8.8e-3 TC2=1.66e-5)
M_BSIM3 16 6 7 7 Bsim3 W=1.08 L=2.0e-6 NRS=1
.MODEL  Bsim3 NMOS (LEVEL=7 VERSION=3.1 MOBMOD=3 CAPMOD=2 PARAMCHK=1 NQSMOD=0
+ TOX=970e-10    XJ=1.4e-6      NCH=1.7e17      UA=1.6e-9
+ U0=700         VSAT=1.0e5     DROUT=3.0       PVAG=5
+ DELTA=0.10     PSCBE2=0       RSH=1.0e-3      PDIBLC2=1e-7
+ VTH0=3.50      VOFF=-0.1      NFACTOR=1.1     
+ LINT=5.90e-7   DLC=5.90e-7    FC=0.5
+ CGSO=1.12e-9   CGSL=0         CGDO=1.05e-14
+ CGDL=1.68e-9   CJ=0           CF=0 
+ CKAPPA=0.20    KT1=-2.07      KT2=0
+ UA1=1.02e-9    NJ=10 )
.ENDS

******************** Power Discrete MOSFET Thermal Model ************************
** 1000V N-Channel MOSFET and TO-247
**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.SUBCKT FQH8N100C_Thermal TH TL
CTHERM1 TH 6 1.12e-5
CTHERM2 6 5  1.53e-3
CTHERM3 5 4  1.82e-2
CTHERM4 4 3  6.45e-2
CTHERM5 3 2  8.12e-2
CTHERM6 2 TL 5.21e-1 
RTHERM1 TH 6 4.00e-4
RTHERM2 6 5  8.10e-3
RTHERM3 5 4  3.40e-2
RTHERM4 4 3  9.10e-2
RTHERM5 3 2  1.02e-1
RTHERM6 2 TL 3.24e-1
.ENDS FQH8N100C_Thermal
**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
** Creation: Jan.-05-2010   Rev.: 0.0
** Fairchild Semiconductor
```